# Вычислить максимальное количество комбинаций и создать генератор

Tags: python

Пытаюсь вычислить максимальное количество комбинаций которое может быть при ключе из 16 символов.
Каждая буква может быть как большой так и маленькой

Может быть любая цифра.
Буквы могут повторяться.
Как правильно вычислить и сделать генератор всех возможных комбинаций?

Пример ключа: c9de-1022-872b-8e17

Comment: Как вычислить количество написано в основах учебника по комбинаторике. Да даже в статье на Википедии написано.

Answer (score 2):

26 маленьких+ 26 больших + 10 цифр = 62 варианта для каждого из 16 мест

Всего 62<sup>16</sup>  возможных комбинаций. Генерировать все - вряд ли  дождётесь.

Comment: 4,767240171×10²⁸

Comment: а если быть точнее  47672401706823533450263330816 комбинаций.

Comment: ~47,67 окталионов, и это всего то 0.04767 ноналионов.

Comment: Ну в принципе, за 13 триллионов лет можно и перебрать.